# Sub-Domain URL Rewrite Issues

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have been scratching my head with this problem for at least two months. I have a classified ads section in our site which has SEO friendly URL's I want to rewrite these url's.  I am not sure if the problem is related to the subdomain for each region.  The URL may look like this:

These are working URL's:

http://milwaukee.storeboard.com/classifieds/for-sale/business/make-incredible-income-while-growing-your-local-economy/425

I want to make it goto this address on our server:

http://milwaukee.storeboard.com/classifieds/viewad.asp?ClassAdID=425

I am using the following code in the web.config file... but no matter what variations I try I cant get it to work..

```
<rule name="Classifieds Ad" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url="^http://([^/]+)/classifieds/.*?(\d+)$" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="http://{R:1}/classifieds/viewad.asp?ClassAdID={R:2}" />
```

The only reason the first link works at this time is because I am using my 404 error page to process the request and then calling the page via MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0 but this is unreliable and can timeout, especially during times of heavy usage. I want to remove this method and use the quick IIS URL Rewrite.

I would really appreciate any help you can provide

Answer (score 0):

Try the below rule

```
<rule name="Classifieds Ad" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url="^classifieds/.*?/(\d+)$" />
 <conditions>
  <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" type=”Pattern” pattern="^(.*)$">
 </conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="{C:0}/classifieds/viewad.asp?ClassAdID={R:1}" />
```

Comment: Will try when there is less activity on the site.. I will let you know.. Many thanks